# Ways to go about preventing duplicate user entries into a list

Tags: c#, list

My program allows me to enter a name (string), description (string), and availability (int) via command-line into a list that I have. I can do this repeatedly, but currently I do not have any method of preventing duplicate entries, so I am able to enter the exact same name as many times as I want. I am trying to add a way to either prevent the user from being able to type the same string name or to only display one entry that has the same name.

```
// Snippet
private static List<string> ProductTypeList; 
private static Dictionary<string, List<Item>> Products;

public class Item
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Description;
            public int availability;

            public Item(string name, string description, int availability)
            {
                Name = name;
                Description = description;
                Availability = availability;

                List<Item> itemList;
                if (Products.ContainsKey(productType))
                {
                    itemList = Products[productType];
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductTypeList.Add(productType);
                    itemList = new List<Item>();
                    Products.Add(productType, itemList);
                }
                itemList.Add(this);
            }
        }
```

In my first switch case is where I thought I should add something like .distinctBy(...) or .Distinct().ToList() to my currentItemList and then a foreach loop to remove any non-unique name values, but because I already have a foreach loop in there which is unrelated, I haven't figured out a workaround yet.

```
case 1: // View Products
    Console.Clear();
    currentItemList = currentItemList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var item in currentItemList)
    {
    item.Display();
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Use a Set instead of a List to prevent duplicates. Also make your item class comparable so the set knows what Items are truly duplicates

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there an alternative to using : IComparable<> or is that the only effective method to achieve the result?

Comment: You can manually scan over your list before adding each element and look for matching attributes... But that will be much slower than using a Set

Comment: Implement IEquatable<Item> interface in `Item` class, and then you can check for duplicates via 'itemList.Contains(this)'. Also it is better to make checks outside of constructor.